# How to use ${currentBuild.result} to indicate "SUCCESS" not "null"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My Jenkins declarative pipeline has the following post action:

```
mail to: '<snip>',
        subject: "Status of pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
        body: "${env.BUILD_URL} has result ${currentBuild.result}"
```

When the build succeeds the content of the email body is:

```
<job name> has result null
```

I understand that the value of ${currentBuild.result}" is null when the job succeeds, but this isn't convenient for the user. What is the recommended way of printing "SUCCESS" (or "FAILURE" etc) in the body message?

Answer (score 59):

Use `${currentBuild.currentResult}` instead.

> currentResult
>
> typically SUCCESS, UNSTABLE, or FAILURE. Will never be null.

The syntax of the available global variables is available at `${YOUR_JENKINS_URL}/pipeline-syntax/globals`. See more info about globals in [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference).

Also see https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/WEBSITE-364

Comment: Thanks @celsiys for pointing that out. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: i added it to my pipeline script but it didn't help (the goal- if the tests failed the build status will be SUCCESS if the tests passed the status will be FAILED and if its mixed pass+failed, the status will be SUCCESS: 

stage('Tests') {
                        steps {
                           script{
                            //running the tests
                                    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.knownBug"
                                    currentBuild.currentResult = "SUCCESS"
                            }
                        }

Answer (score 2):

You can add mail step inside post step in pipeline as below :

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Example Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Hello, JDK'
        }
       }
     }
post {
 success {
     echo "${env.BUILD_URL} has result success"
      }
 failure {
     echo "${env.BUILD_URL} has result fail"
      }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I knew that and have used it before. But that method is a bit long-winded compared to 'always'.

Comment: If you use 'always' it will execute either if build fail or success.

Comment: Yes, but that may be ok if you just want to send an email.

Comment: Yes agree, If you want to just pass the information on completion of build. But if you have different messages for success and failure of the build then the you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentBuild contains the following property. You can use them according to your need.

_class,
actions,
artifacts,
building,
description,
displayName,
duration,
estimatedDuration,
executor,
fullDisplayName,
id,
keepLog,
number,
queueId,
result,
timestamp,
URL,
changeSets,
culprits,
nextBuild,
previousBuild,
number